# Masstransit. Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MySqlConnection'

Tags: mysql, .net-core, identity, dbcontext, masstransit

Problems arose during the implementation of the project.
The task is to catch the event and do some work in the database.
It would seem that everything is simple, but I get an error
"Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MySqlConnection'." I think this error is due to the fact that the dbContext doesn't really exist. And I don't understand how to forward it through MassTransit.

**Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServerConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUserDTO, IdentityRole>();
        new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUserDTO), typeof(IdentityRole), services)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        //AutoMapper
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));


        #region MassTransit RabbitMq

        services.AddScoped<CreateUserConsumer>();
        services.AddMassTransit(c =>
        {
            c.AddConsumer<CreateUserConsumer>();
        });
                  

       services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(conf =>
       {

           conf.Host(Configuration["Rabbit:Host"], host =>
           {
               host.Username(Configuration["Rabbit:Username"]);
               host.Password(Configuration["Rabbit:Password"]);
           });             

           conf.ReceiveEndpoint(Configuration["Rabbit:ReceiveEndpoint"], e =>
           {
               e.PrefetchCount = 16;
               e.UseMessageRetry(n => n.Interval(3, 100));

               #region                  
               e.Consumer<CreateUserConsumer>(provider);                  
               #endregion

           });             

       }));

        services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
        services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
        services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());

        services.AddScoped(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>().CreateRequestClient<CreateUserConsumer>());

        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();

        #endregion


        #region Services 
        services.AddScoped<IAuth, AuthService>();
        #endregion
    }
```

**Consumer:**

```
public class CreateUserConsumer : IConsumer<IUserCreate>
{
    private IAuth _authService;
    private IMapper _mapper;      
    public CreateUserConsumer(IAuth _authService, IMapper _mapper)
    {
        this._authService = _authService;
        this._mapper = _mapper;
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IUserCreate> context)
    {
        var model = _mapper.Map<IUserCreate, UserRegisterDTO>(context.Message);                      
        var s = _authService.RegisterAsync(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**AuthService:**

```
public class AuthService : IAuth
    {
        private  UserManager<ApplicationUserDTO> _userManager;
        private  RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private  IMapper mapper;

        public AuthService(
            UserManager<ApplicationUserDTO> userManager, 
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,          
            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public string Register(UserRegisterDTO model)
        {
            try
            {
                var newUser = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName); //**Exception**
                if (newUser != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("blablabla");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                var s = exp;
            }
            return "";           
        }
}
```

**Error:**

```
 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
       Failed executing DbCommand (121ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedUserName_0='?' (Size = 256)],
 CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='1200']
       SELECT `a`.`Id`, `a`.`AccessFailedCount`, `a`.`ConcurrencyStamp`, `a`.`Email`, `a`.`EmailConfirmed`, `a`.`FIO`,
 `a`.`LockoutEnabled`, `a`.`LockoutEnd`, `a`.`NormalizedEmail`,
 `a`.`NormalizedUserName`, `a`.`PasswordHash`, `a`.`PhoneNumber`,
 `a`.`PhoneNumberConfirmed`, `a`.`SecurityStamp`,
 `a`.`TwoFactorEnabled`, `a`.`UserName`
       FROM `AspNetUsers` AS `a`
       WHERE `a`.`NormalizedUserName` = @__normalizedUserName_0
       LIMIT 1 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
       An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Auth.API.Context.AuthDbContext'.
       System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
       Object name: 'MySqlConnection'.
          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.VerifyNotDisposed() in
 C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line
 707
```

I think the error is due to the fact that when _UserManager is called, the database context is no longer there.

Tell me what am I doing wrong?!?!

Comment: Your configuration, using both AddMassTransit, and creating and configuring the bus yourself, isn't a good option. I'd revisit [the docs](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core) to get back to the standard config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's the problem:

```
    var s = _authService.RegisterAsync(model);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
```

I believe even your IDE gives a warning "accessing a disposed closure" since you are neither awaiting the task nor returning it.

Most probably this will work

```
return _authService.RegisterAsync(model);
```

The issue might be somewhere else since I don't see the code where `DbContext` is registered.

In addition, I'd recommend registering MassTransit and all the required dependencies as it is [described in the docs](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core).

Comment: Oh my God !!! And I didn't notice the elephant!
Alexey,Thank!